# Navigate back to home page if there is no user interaction for x duration (user is idle)

Tags: c#, android, timer, maui, .net-maui

I am working on a **self management app** and I need to implement an **inactivity timer** or something similar to know if the user is idling (without interacting with a view for x duration) so when this happens it returns to the home page.

Is this possible? Already check app lifecycle docs and doesn't found any relevant info.

I was thinking of making a timer per view that when the time comes x redirects but it seems less than optimal. Is there a way to integrate it directly into the application or do I really have to set a timer per view?

Sorry if my question is not clear. Please ask and I can update if it doesn't make sense.

Comment: The timer could live in the App class instead of on each page

Comment: and every user action on every view then calls a method (in App class) that restarts the timer. One way to do this is to make a custom subclass of each UI class you use. Add that call to override of each relevant method. I don't know if there is some easier way to do this.

Comment: that helps me a lot, i thought on make something with shell navigation, like a timer on the shell class that if the route didn't change for 5 mins, it go home, but don't know if that would work. Over the weekend I will try to do it both ways and I will update the results. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Cross platform code (common)

```
using Timer = System.Timers.Timer;
```

**App.xaml.cs**

```
Timer IdleTimer = new Timer( 60 * 1000);  //each 1 minute

public App()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    MainPage = new AppShell();

    IdleTimer.Elapsed += Idleimer_Elapsed;
    IdleTimer.Start();
}

async void Idleimer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(":::Elapsed");
    if (MainThread.IsMainThread)
        await Shell.Current.Navigation.PopToRootAsync();
    else
        MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () => await Shell.Current.Navigation.PopToRootAsync());}

public void ResetIdleTimer()
{
    IdleTimer.Stop();
    IdleTimer.Start();
}
```

#### Android

To detect user interaction on Android you can relay on [OnUserInteraction()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/android.app.activity.onuserinteraction).

[Android docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#onUserInteraction())

**MainActivity.cs**

```
public override void OnUserInteraction()
{
    base.OnUserInteraction();
    (App.Current as App).ResetIdleTimer();
}
```

#### iOS

on ios you can listen to touche events at application level
[source](https://www.pranavkhandelwal.com/blog/2015/11/1/detecting-user-inactivityidle-time-for-xamarinios).

**Program.cs**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   UIApplication.Main(args, typeof(CustomApplication), typeof(AppDelegate));
}
```

**CustomApplication.cs**

```
public class CustomApplication : UIApplication
{
    public CustomApplication() : base()
    {
    }

    public CustomApplication(IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
    {
    }

    public CustomApplication(Foundation.NSObjectFlag t) : base(t)
    {
    }
    public override void SendEvent(UIEvent uievent)
    {
        if (uievent.Type == UIEventType.Touches)
        {
            if (uievent.AllTouches.Cast<UITouch>().Any(t => t.Phase == UITouchPhase.Began))
            {
                (App.Current as App).ResetIdleTimer();
            }
        }

        base.SendEvent(uievent);
    }
```

#### Windows

For windows you can listen to some native window events like [WM_NCACTIVATE: 0x0086](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-ncactivate) or [WM_SETCURSOR 0x0020](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/wm-setcursor) or [WM_MOUSEACTIVATE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-mouseactivate).

I am sure there is a more efficient way which listens to mouse cursor moving event, for some reasons is not reported at this level (for example [WM_MOUSEMOVE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-mousemove)).

**MauiProgram.cs**

```
            .ConfigureLifecycleEvents(events =>
            {
#if WINDOWS
                events
                    .AddWindows(windows => windows
                        .OnPlatformMessage((window, args) =>
                        {
                            if (args.MessageId == Convert.ToUInt32("0x0086", 16) ||
                                args.MessageId == Convert.ToUInt32("0x0020", 16) ||
                                args.MessageId == Convert.ToUInt32("0x0021", 16) )
                            {
                                (App.Current as App).ResetIdleTimer();
                            }
                        }));
#endif
```

Comment: Sorry for delay, cannot tested until today. Very useful answer (should be used for docs). actually it's working as expected and would like to have (in future versions) a common method to interact on the main app that contain your code (working as multiplat but in 1 line haha) thanks!